# Compare a table with itrself in SQL?

Tags: sql

The output of below query is:

query:

```
SELECT CategoryID
FROM Categories
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories as c WHERE c.CategoryID < Categories.CategoryID);
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
```

Table Categories:

```
CategoryID  CategoryName
1           Beverages
2           Condiments
3           Confections
4           Dairy Products
```

I wanna trace sub query `(SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories as c WHERE c.CategoryID < Categories.CategoryID)` . Do records compare one by one? Why does not the ID 1 come out on the output?

Comment: Imagine a loop over the first query, for each record it executes your sub-query and checks if it returns any records *(that's what `EXISTS` does)*.  So, for `CategoryID = 1` it then does `SELECT categoryID FROM Categories WHERE categoryID < 1`, as there are no such records, the `EXISTS` check fails, and that input row is not returned.  When it does it again for `categoryID = 2`, the sub-query finds one records, and so the `EXISTS` check succeeds.

Comment: Thank you. I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXISTS` is used for the existence of any record in a subquery.

when you use `SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories as c WHERE c.CategoryID < Categories.CategoryID`

there isn't match any row from `CategoryID = 1`

If you want to get `CategoryID = 1`

try to use

```
c.CategoryID <= Categories.CategoryID
```

instead of

```
c.CategoryID < Categories.CategoryID
```

to contain `CategoryID = 1` row.